# Relevance of Research Papers from another field for Grad Admission

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, united-states, physics, changing-fields

I am a student of Indian nationality, currently pursuing my bachelor's in Electronics and Communication Engineering. I wish to pursue a Ph.D. and later a career in astronomy (with an inclination to Radio Astronomy) and have done relevant research internships and projects in the same. However, I have no publications in this area.
Alongside this, I have worked on research in antenna engineering with a professor in my institute and we have published 2 papers in international conferences.

My query is: for graduate admissions, will my research papers in antenna engineering have any value and consideration or are only research papers in Astronomy looked out for?

Comment: Yes, that would have value as antennas are important to astronomy.  Beware that there are few jobs in astronomy.